# On Linux ZFS Server - What is eating my memory?

Tags: linux, zfs, linux-kernel, zfsonlinux

Our monitoring tool regularly reports low memory for one of our servers running ZFS.

```
# free -g
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             125          84          39           0           2          40
Swap:             49           0          49
```

After googling I found that ZFS is quite memory hungry with it's cache. However it uses "only" 44.9 GB (or do I read the arc_summary incorrectly:

```
# arc_summary
...
ARC size (current):                                    85.2 %   53.5 GiB
        Target size (adaptive):                        85.8 %   53.9 GiB
        Min size (hard limit):                          6.2 %    3.9 GiB
        Max size (high water):                           16:1   62.8 GiB
...
```

So:

```
   125 GB Memory Total
 -  40 GB Available
 -  54 GB ZFS Cache
 -  6 GB Processes displayed by ps (vsz)
 =====
    25 GB ????
```

As requested: (cat /proc/meminfo):

```
MemTotal:       131665836 kB
MemFree:        41276812 kB
MemAvailable:   42553236 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:            77304 kB
SwapCached:        24236 kB
Active:            60604 kB
Inactive:          83652 kB
Active(anon):      12712 kB
Inactive(anon):    66792 kB
Active(file):      47892 kB
Inactive(file):    16860 kB
Unevictable:       11948 kB
Mlocked:           11948 kB
SwapTotal:      52428796 kB
SwapFree:       52373500 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:           464 kB
AnonPages:         55112 kB
Mapped:            56168 kB
Shmem:              2296 kB
KReclaimable:    2084224 kB
Slab:           65863304 kB
SReclaimable:    2084224 kB
SUnreclaim:     63779080 kB
KernelStack:       13856 kB
PageTables:         3964 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    118261712 kB
Committed_AS:     361476 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:     2948856 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:            31232 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:    88585508 kB
DirectMap2M:    43186176 kB
DirectMap1G:     4194304 kB
```

systemd-cgtop -m -n 1

```
Control Group                             Tasks   %CPU   Memory  Input/s Output/s
/                                           787      -    86.1G        -        -
system.slice                                 98      -     2.0G        -        -
system.slice/cron.service                     1      -     1.9G        -        -
system.slice/systemd-journald.service         1      -    32.5M        -        -
```

The rest is under 30 MB

slabtop --once

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 99549552 / 109644976 (90.8%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 3498896 / 3498896 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 127 / 196 (64.8%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 61511851.41K / 65204041.81K (94.3%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.59K / 16.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME
16127096 14742570  91%    0.50K 503977       32   8063632K kmalloc-512
15970928 14903038  93%    0.38K 380264       42   6084224K dmu_buf_impl_t
15562646 14573457  93%    0.97K 483843       33  15482976K dnode_t
13621377 13469293  98%    0.24K 412769       33   3302152K sa_cache
13543561 13468664  99%    1.08K 649473       29  20783136K zfs_znode_cache
10347792 10347792 100%    0.19K 246376       42   1971008K dentry
5660031 5660011  99%    0.31K 110981       51   1775696K arc_buf_hdr_t_full
5105792 3032351  59%    0.03K  39889      128    159556K kmalloc-32
3003328 2081202  69%    0.06K  46927       64    187708K kmalloc-64
2873949 2097731  72%    0.10K  73691       39    294764K abd_t
2225216 272877  12%    0.25K  69538       32    556304K kmalloc-256
672042 670950  99%    0.09K  16001       42     64004K kmalloc-96
619191 488804  78%    0.08K  12141       51     48564K arc_buf_t
565984 538604  95%    1.00K  17687       32    565984K kmalloc-1k
485063 460395  94%    8.00K 122762        4   3928384K kmalloc-8k
483359 463686  95%   16.00K 244241        2   7815712K zio_buf_comb_16384
418272 215389  51%    1.00K  13071       32    418272K zio_buf_comb_1024
392576 392576 100%    0.06K   6134       64     24536K kmalloc-rcl-64
326080 326080 100%    0.12K  10190       32     40760K scsi_sense_cache
256494  44775  17%    0.19K   6107       42     48856K kmalloc-192
189224 189224 100%    0.07K   3379       56     13516K Acpi-Operand
```

I need to lower memory usage. I could reduce the zfs cache, but that it not the only memory hog, so it might make more sense to reduce the 35 unknown GB.

How can I find out what is using the memory?

Comment: [Check this](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) You can try this command: `ps -e -o pid,vsz,comm= | sort -n -k 2`

Comment: @Mrwut I used the "size" of ps for the 28 GB, if I use your command it's 5 GB more, that's still 35 GB unaccounted for

Comment: Please edit your question to add the contents of `cat /proc/meminfo`  and if a systemd distro  `systemd-cgtop -m -n 1`    On Linux these provide more specific information on how memory is used, by what.

Comment: @JohnMahowald Thanks for your reply. I updated the question. Can you make something out of these numbers?

Comment: Can you show the output of `top -o RES` and `smem -tw`?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the first 50 lines or so of `slabtop --once`   Your meminfo shows 95 GB (76% of your MemTotal) in  SUnreclaim, which is a lot of kernel objects.

Comment: @JohnMahowald Thanks for the follow up. I updated the question with the command and all the other values so it makes sense. The difference is smaller now (yey), only 25 GB unaccounted for.